# Augmenting feature vector with bias in SVM: effect on kernel matrix

Tags: classification, svm, optimization, libsvm

It is easier to optimise a SVM without an offset term $b$ since we get rid of one of the linear constraints in the dual formulation. If an offset is still needed, it has been suggested that the feature vector $x\in\mathbf{R}^n$ is augmented by a constant term. Let's call this term $d$, then $x' = [x; d]\in\mathbf{R}^{n+1}$.

Suykens et al 2014 ([page 9 in Regularization, Optimization, Kernels, and Support Vector Machines](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=25TaBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA9&ots=g-iM9BjJC8&dq=svm%20add%20offset%20dual%20coordinate%20kernel&pg=PA9#v=onepage&q&f=true)) write that

> As a side-effect, the offset $d^2$ is then also regularized in the new term $||w||^2$. Nevertheless, if desired, the effect of this additional regularization can be made arbitrarily weak by re-scaling the fixed additional feature value *from one to a larger value*.

A similar argument was made here [by Sobi in a different thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184272/why-is-the-bias-term-in-svm-estimated-separately-instead-of-an-extra-dimension)

However, if we increase $d$ (to make its effect on regularization smaller) we make the effect on the kernel matrix larger. E.g. for a linear kernel and another augmented sample $y' = [y; d]$ we get

$$
K(x',y') = x'^\top y' = x^\top y + d^2 = K(x,y) + d^2
$$

Is this effect on the kernel matrix problematic? Should we hence *not* make $d$ too large?

Comment: My own question [Should we account for the intercept term when kernelizing algorithms?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/232562/should-we-account-for-the-intercept-term-when-kernelizing-algorithms) might shed some light onto this.

Comment: It does partially, though my question is a bit different: I know I want to include a bias term, but I want to use the 'trick' of including it in $x$ to ease optimisation. So does this 'trick' lead me astray when I chose a large $d$ or is it ok?

Comment: If $d$ is really large, it's coefficient will be small (it's a tradeoff), therefore it won't be severely penalized. The converse is also true, if you make $d$ small it's associated coefficient will be huge, and more prone to penalization.