# What would be the solution of Ridge regression, if there is an intercept?

Tags: regression, ridge-regression

So far I've only seen this solution: $$\beta = (X^TX+\lambda I)^{-1}X^Ty.$$

But I assume this is for the case: $$y=\beta X+ \epsilon$$

What would be solution for the more general case:

$$y=\beta X+ \beta_0 +\epsilon$$

And how can I derive it?

Comment: $$\beta = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$$ is not a solution to ridge regression (except perhaps in the degenerate case that no regularization is applied). Perhaps you mean $$\beta = (X^TX + \lambda I)^{-1}X^Ty,$$ where $\lambda >0$ is some well-chosen scalar, but that's meeting you more than half-way. There is an ambiguity in the question: do you want to regularize $\beta_0$ or not?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I copied the wrong equation. How would it be including the intercept? I do not want to regularize $\beta_0$.

Comment: I already wrote it down, in the second equation: append $\beta_0$ to your coefficient vector, and a column of 1s to $X$. This is just as you estimate an intercept for ordinary least squares regression.

Comment: Isn't this thoroughly answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69205?

Comment: My question is different. I just wanted to know why the intercept was not included and how the form of the solution would change if it was.

Comment: *Any variable you like* is included in the general formulation of that other thread.  I don't see any place where intercepts were excluded.

Comment: Yeah but some sources use $$y=\beta X+ \beta_0 +\epsilon$$ instead, so in this case the solution did not make sense.

Comment: Again, this is solely a matter of how you choose to write down $\beta$ and $X$. Separating it out from the rest of the coefficients, or including it among them (with a corresponding column of 1s in $X$), is **exactly the same**. Let me pose it to you this way: what's the OLS estimator for $\beta, \beta_0$ when you write $y= X\beta+ \beta_0 +\epsilon$?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The outline of how to derive the ridge regression solution in [How to derive the ridge regression solution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69205) is complete. I think you're simply stumbling over differences in notation; some sources include a column of 1s in $X$ and an intercept in $\beta$ and others don't, instead writing $y=\beta_0 + X\beta + \epsilon$. You have to pay close attention to what you're reading.

---

Centering $y$ and centering the columns of $X$ produces a result where the intercept $\beta_0 =0$  exactly. This is also completely standard, because then estimating intercept can be ignored entirely, yielding the form that you are familiar with. (Thanks for [Sextus](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/164061/sextus-empiricus) for making this connection in comments.)

---

If this isn't the source of confusion, and you really do wish to regularize the intercept, then using $$\beta = (X^TX + \lambda I)^{-1}X^Ty$$ does the job: $X$ includes a column of 1s plus any "features" or "independent variables," and $\beta$ includes the intercept $\beta_0$.

If you do not wish to regularize the intercept (as is standard practice; see [Reason for not shrinking the bias (intercept) term in regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86991/reason-for-not-shrinking-the-bias-intercept-term-in-regression)), just define $\gamma = \begin{bmatrix}\beta_0 \\ \beta\end{bmatrix}$ and write down $$\gamma = (X^TX + \lambda A)^{-1}X^Ty,$$ where $$A= \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0  \\ 0 & I\end{bmatrix}$$ and the first column of $X$ is 1s. This "turns off" the regularization of $\beta_0$. It distinguishes between regularizing $\beta$ and applying no regularization to $\beta$.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense. Why don't most textbooks use this solution? I really don't see how y=0 when x=0 in most cases. I would prefer if they showed a more general solution than the degenerate case. Anyways thanks!

Comment: I think you're simply stumbling over differences in notation; some sources include a column of 1s in $X$ and an intercept in $\beta$ and others don't, instead writing $y=\beta_0 + X\beta + \epsilon$. You have to pay close attention to what you're reading.

Comment: @Caterina, the reason why is maybe because many solutions will center the variables in order to get a solution where the intercept is not regularised. Then the regression on the centered data is performed without an intercept. $y= X\beta+ \epsilon$ is general because it can include an intercept, and if you don't want the intercept regularised as part of $X$ then you can use centering.

Comment: Just another moan about ML language: in a linear model, calling the intercept term $\beta_0$ "the bias" only really makes sense if you have already centred all the data