# Does L2-normalization of ridge regression punish intercept? If not, how to solve its derivative?

Tags: machine-learning, ridge-regression

I am new to ML. I was informed that the L2-normalization of ridge regression does not punish the intercept $\theta_{0}$. As in the cost function:
$$
\nabla_{\theta}J(\theta)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(h_{\vec \theta}(x^{(i)})-y^{(i)})^2+\lambda\sum_{j=1}^{n}{\theta_{j}^{2}}
$$
The L2-normalization term $\lambda\sum_{j=1}^{n}{\theta_{j}^{2}}$ only sums from $j=1$ to $n$, not from $j=0$ to $n$. I also read that:

> in most cases (all cases?), you're better off not regularizing $\theta_{0}$,
>   since its unlikely to reduce overfitting and shrinks the space of
>   representable functions

which comes from the last answer of user48956 of [Why is a zero-intercept linear regression model predicts better than a model with an intercept?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21738/why-is-a-zero-intercept-linear-regression-model-predicts-better-than-a-model-wit/254627#254627)

I am confused about how to solve the derivative of the cost function, since:
$$
\nabla_{\theta}J(\theta)=\frac{1}{2}（X\theta-Y）^{T}（X\theta-Y）+\lambda(\theta^{'})^{T}\theta^{'},
$$
where $\theta^{'}=\left[
 \begin{matrix}
   \theta_{1} \\
   \theta_{2} \\
   ...\\
   \theta_{n}
  \end{matrix}
  \right]$ , $\theta=\left[
 \begin{matrix}
   \theta_{0} \\   
   \theta_{1} \\
   ...\\
   \theta_{n}
  \end{matrix}
  \right]$ and $X=\left[
 \begin{matrix}
   1 & X_{1}^{(1)} & X_{2}^{(1)} & ...& X_{n}^{(1)}  \\   
   1 & X_{1}^{(2)} & X_{2}^{(2)} & ...& X_{n}^{(2)} \\
   ...\\
   1 & X_{1}^{(m)} & X_{2}^{(m)} & ...& X_{n}^{(m)}
  \end{matrix}
  \right]$.

$\theta^{'}$ and $\theta$ are different. Hence they cannot be mixed from my point of view. And the derivative is about $\theta$，which contains $\theta^{'}$. After googling and viewing the questions on this forum, there is still no way for me to get the solution:
$$
\theta=(X^TX+\lambda*I)^{-1}X^TY
$$
Can anybody give me a clue? Thanks in advance for your help!

However, I think there are two quick fixes to this problem:

First of all, we do not add the all 1 column to $X$. Namely $X=\left[
 \begin{matrix}
    X_{1}^{(1)} & X_{2}^{(1)} & ...& X_{n}^{(1)}  \\   
   X_{1}^{(2)} & X_{2}^{(2)} & ...& X_{n}^{(2)} \\
   ...\\
  X_{1}^{(m)} & X_{2}^{(m)} & ...& X_{n}^{(m)}
  \end{matrix}
  \right]$. That is to say we do not include the intercept at all in the model:$$ y=\theta_{1}X_{1}+\theta_{2}X_{2}+...+\theta_{n}X_{n}.$$
I believe this method is adopted in the classic book *Machine Learning in Action* by Peter Harrington which I am currently reading. In its implementation of ridge regression (P166 and P177 if you also have the book), all the $X$ passed to ridge regression does not have the all 1 column. So no intercept is fitted at all.

Secondly, the intercept is also being punished in reality.

> scikit's logistic regression regularizes the intercept by default.

which once again comes from the last answer of user48956 of [Why is a zero-intercept linear regression model predicts better than a model with an intercept?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21738/why-is-a-zero-intercept-linear-regression-model-predicts-better-than-a-model-wit/254627#254627)

Both of the two quick fixes lead to the solution
$$
\theta=(X^TX+\lambda*I)^{-1}X^TY.
$$

So can the derivative of L2-normalization of ridge regression actually being solved or are just solved by quick fixes?

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86991. The answer to your Q is that everything can be solved: simply decompose the first term into theta_0 and theta_prime. You can immediately solve for optimal theta_0: it's the overall mean. Leading to your "quick fix #1" as the proper solution for theta_prime on the mean-subtracted data.

Comment: The second solution is pretty universally considered incorrect.  The penalization of the intercept is one of a few design errors in sklearn.

Comment: @MatthewDrury I think I mentioned a hack to "fix" this and made you sad. But I want to tell OP that the hack is make a huge intercept, such as 1e9. Then the regularization takes little effect on it.

Comment: Yah, you remeber correctly, everytime i do that i die inside a little.

Comment: @amoeba Thanks a lot! I work out the solution in my answer under your guidance. Can you help me check it? What's more, I discover that Machine Learning in Action subtracts mean from $Y$ and not adds the all 1 column  to $X$ which are both right way to go. However, when doing feature standardizing, it divides $X-\mu$ by variance not by standard deviation!  I asked another question for this: [not by standard deviation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/322226/is-this-a-mistake-in-the-feature-standardization-of-ridge-regression-in-book-mac) Can you help me again on this question? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*The Elements of Statistical Learning* by Hastie et al. points out in P63 that:

> the intercept $\theta_{0}$ has been left out of the penalty term

Furthermore, it says:

> The ridge solutions are not equivariant under scaling of the inputs,
>   and so one normally standardizes the inputs before solving (3.41) (3.41
>   is the cost function). It can be shown (Exercise 3.5) that the solution
>   to (3.41) can be separated into two parts, after reparametrization
>   using centered inputs: each $X_{j}^{(i)}$ gets replaced by
>   $X_{j}^{(i)}-\overline{x_{j}}.$ We estimate $\theta_{0}$ by
>   $\overline{y}=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}y^{(i)}$ The remaining
>   coefficients get estimated by a ridge regression without intercept,
>   using the centered $X_{j}^{(i)}$. Henceforth we assume that this
>   centering has been done, so that the input matrix $X$ has $n$ (rather
>   than $n + 1$) columns.

Although I wonder why *The Elements of Statistical Learning* first suggests feature standardization and then only feature centering is conducted. Maybe to agree with Exercise 3.5 which only uses feature centering.

Anyway, I believe it's right to apply z-score standardization to features. So I now try to solve the derivative of the cost function of ridge regression following the suggestion of the above commenter amoeba. Thanks him or her a lot!

First, the cost function:
$$
\nabla_{ \theta}J(\theta)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(y_{i}-\theta_{0}-\frac{X_{1}^{(i)}-\overline{X_1}}{\sigma_1}\theta_1-\frac{X_{2}^{(i)}-\overline{X_2}}{\sigma_2}\theta_2-...-\frac{X_{n}^{(i)}-\overline{X_n}}{\sigma_n}\theta_n)^2+\lambda\sum_{j=1}^{n}{\theta_{j}^{2}},
$$
where $\overline{X_j}$ is the mean of attribute $X_{j}$ and $\sigma_j$ is the standard deviation of $X_{j}$.
To make it shorter:
$$
\nabla_{ \theta}J(\theta)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(y_{i}-\theta_{0}-\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{X_j^{(i)}-\overline{X_j}}{\sigma_{j}}\theta_j)^2+\lambda\sum_{j=1}^{n}{\theta_{j}^{2}}
$$
Now we first compute the value of $\theta_0$ in the above expression by setting the derivative with respect to $\theta_0$ equal to zero. Since $\lambda\sum_{j=1}^{n}{\theta_{j}^{2}}$ does not have $\theta_{0}$, we get:
$$
\nabla_{ \theta_0}J(\theta)=-\sum_{i=1}^{m}(y_{i}-\theta_{0}-\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{X_j^{(i)}-\overline{X_j}}{\sigma_{j}}\theta_j)=0
$$
That is:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{m}(y_{i}-\theta_{0})-\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{X_j^{(i)}-\overline{X_j}}{\sigma_{j}}\theta_j=0
$$
As $$\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{X_j^{(i)}-\overline{X_j}}{\sigma_{j}}\theta_j=0$$ (because $\overline{X_j}$ is the mean of attribute $X_{j}$ ), so now we have $$\sum_{i=1}^{m}(y_{i}-\theta_{0})=0,$$ obviously:
$$\theta_0=\overline{y}=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}y^{(i)}$$

So the intercept of feature-standardized ridge regression is always $\overline{y}$. **Hence if we first centralize $Y$ by subtracting its mean (get  $(y_i)^{'}$ for data example $i$), not include all 1 column in $X$, and then do feature standardization on $X$ (get $(X_j^{(i)})^{'}$ for $X_{j}$ of data example $i$)**, the cost function will simply be
$$
\nabla_{ \theta}J(\theta)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{m}((y_{i})^{'}-\sum_{j=1}^{n}(X_j^{(i)})^{'}\theta_j)^2+\lambda\sum_{j=1}^{n}{\theta_{j}^{2}}
$$
That is
$$
\nabla_{\theta}J(\theta)=\frac{1}{2}（X^{'}\theta-Y^{'}）^{T}（X^{'}\theta-Y^{'}）+\lambda(\theta)^{T}\theta, 
$$
where $\theta=\left[
 \begin{matrix}
   \theta_1  \\   
   \theta_2 \\
   ...\\
   \theta_n
  \end{matrix}
  \right]$, $X^{'}$ does not have all 1 column and standardized of $X$, $Y^{'}$ is centered with respect to $Y$.
Now $\theta$ (without $\theta_0$) can be solved with:
$$
\theta=((X^{'})^TX^{'}+\lambda*I)^{-1}(X^{'})^TY^{'}
$$
For standardized features, the linear model will be 
$$
y=\overline{y}+\theta{_1}X_1^{'}+\theta{_2}X_2^{'}+...+\theta{_n}X_n^{'}---(1),
$$
where
$$X_i^{'}=\frac{X_{i}-\overline{X_i}}{\sigma_i}---(2)$$
If we use (2) in (1) as suggested in the answer of [Plasty Grove](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184209/multiple-regression-how-to-calculate-the-predicted-value-after-feature-normali). So for origin input data, the linear model will be
$$
y=\overline{y}+\frac{X_{1}-\overline{X_1}}{\sigma_1}\theta_1+\frac{X_{2}-\overline{X_2}}{\sigma_2}\theta_2+...+\frac{X_{n}-\overline{X_n}}{\sigma_n}\theta_n
$$
That is 
$$
y=\frac{\theta_1}{\sigma_1}X_1+\frac{\theta_2}{\sigma_2}X_2+...+\frac{\theta_n}{\sigma_n}X_n+\overline{y}-\frac{\overline{X_1}}{\sigma_1}\theta_1-\frac{\overline{X_2}}{\sigma_2}\theta_2-...-\frac{\overline{X_n}}{\sigma_n}\theta_n
$$
That's why after we solve coefficients of standardized features, to return coefficients of origin input data (unstandardized features), we must return $\theta_i/\sigma_i$

Comment: Nice detailed example. A couple of comments: you comment on the effect of centering $Y$, but to omit an intercept term and obtain correct estimates, one must center all $X$ features as well. However I agree this example agrees with the rationale for not penalizing the intercept term (to obtain consistent inference). Second, intuition should serve for something here. We all accept that predicting $Y$ by its mean is akin to a 0 parameter model, so to get the additive effect of $X$ in the model, we mustn't penalize the term which merely catches the mean-Y effect in the presence of $X$.