# Intercept and slope of ridge regression model

Tags: regression, ridge-regression

When we compute a Ridge regression model, do we need to compute the intercept separately from the slopes? As you know, the estimated $\beta$ for the ridge regression model is given by:

$\hat \beta = (X^TX - \lambda I_n)^{-1} X^T y$

But this formula is only for the slope parameters, excluding the intercept.

I'm just operating on pure intuition here, but can't we just append the constant column to $X$...

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_{11} & x_{12} & \ldots\\
1 & x_{21} & x_{22} & \ldots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{bmatrix}

...and add a diagonal element at the beginning of $\lambda I_n$ with the value 0?

\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots\\
0 & \lambda & 0 & \ldots \\
0 & 0 & \lambda  & \ldots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: I don't have the time to work this out in detail, but I believe it can be shown that what you propose is *not* the solution to the minimisation problem that ridge regression is meant to solve (without penalising the intercept). Maybe this helps:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/322101/does-l2-normalization-of-ridge-regression-punish-intercept-if-not-how-to-solve